# Why this definition for "symmetry transformation"?

Tags: definition, mathematical-physics, symmetry, quantum-field-theory

This question concerns section 8.5.1 in [these notes](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-7-conslaw.pdf):

> [image]

I don't understand why a *symmetry transformation* is defined as such. What implications is there if $\delta \mathcal L$ is a total derivative? Is there an intuitive way to see this?

Comment: Please take screenshots or copy down the information yourself into the question, so that your question will still make sense if external content is removed.

Comment: The tag `[field-theory]` refers to the word "field" in the sense of abstract algebra ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))). I'm not sure what the right tag is, but I guessed maybe this is `[quantum-field-theory]`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Strictly speaking, it's still classical field theory, but on the one hand, that tag doesn't exist [yet], and on the other hand, this material is almost certainly being learnt in the context of introductory quantum field theory, so the QFT tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bit of a strange definition of "symmetry transformation", since there are other kinds of transformations which are symmetries (Gauge transformations, for instance). But at least here, if you change the Lagrangian by a surface term, the action will vanish if the fields vanish at infinity. This is a standard assumption of quantum field theory. Likewise you could work on a compact manifold and force the fields to vanish at the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that is called a symmetry transformation is that the equations of motion which are derived from that action principle are invariant under such a symmetry. Notice a total derivative term integrates out under the conditions mentioned in levitopher's answer. That is my understanding of the motivation of the term. Physicists care about equations of motion (solutions of the Euler Lagrange equations derived from the action)